# using BigIntegers inside for loop goes into infinite loop

Tags: java, biginteger

trying to find sum of bigIntegers with 2 set bits but its looping infinite with 100% cpu usage however using JDK1.8 need suggestions

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("5");   
int sum = 0;
for(BigInteger i=BigInteger.valueOf(1); i.compareTo(bi)<=0 ; i.add(BigInteger.ONE))
{
    //System.out.println("inside loop");
    int k = i.bitCount();
    if(k==2)
    {
        sum.add(i);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Is it valid to use bigintegers inside for loop or Is there any other way to achieve the functionality

Comment: It seems to me that they have already answered this question... i.add(BigInteger.ONE) does this work???, is i increased??? or maybe its was not.... check the question you posted previously...

Comment: Sorry maybe it was not you or you have delete the question?'

Comment: yes its incrementing but not stopping  i.compareTo(bigint)<=0  seems to be the issue

Comment: i.add(BigInteger.ONE) does not increment i @resueman answer does since it reassign it...

Comment: Why use `BigInteger`? `int sum=0; for (int i=1; i<=5; i++) { if (Integer.bitCount(i) == 2) sum+=i; }` will do it much faster.

Comment: You say it loops infinitely, yet it doesn't even compile. `sum.add(i)` doesn't work for `int sum`. If you instead used `BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO`, then you'd also need `sum = sum.add(i)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `BigInteger`s are immutable. When you do `i.add(BigInteger.ONE)`, it doesn't modify `i`. It just returns a new `BigInteger` value.

Instead, you should assign the result back to `i`.

```
for(BigInteger i = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    i.compareTo(bi) <= 0; 
    i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)){ //Reassigning back to i
```

What you're currently doing is similar to a loop like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 5; i + 1) //Same problem, using ints
```